# Static files inside `public` folder not being served (NextJS custom server using ExpressJS)

Tags: express, next.js

I am working on `NextJS` app. And I have made a custom server using `ExpressJS`. The problem is when I run the app using the custom server the app cannot find the static files inside the `public` folder.

> Note: I don't have any problem  When I run the app using `next dev`

My server

```js
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const path = require('path');

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const prefix = (path = '') => `/:lang(en|tr)?`.concat(path);

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();

    server.get(prefix('/'), (req, res) => app.render(req, res, '/', req.query));
    server.get(prefix('/agency'), (req, res) => app.render(req, res, '/agency', req.query));
    server.get(prefix('/cases'), (req, res) => app.render(req, res, '/cases', req.query));
    server.get(prefix('/blog'), (req, res) => app.render(req, res, '/blog', req.query));
    server.get(prefix('/contact'), (req, res) => app.render(req, res, '/contact', req.query));

    server.get(prefix('/image.png'), (req, res) => app.render(req, res, '/public/images/avatar01.jpg', req.query));

    server.listen(port, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are not implementing a fallback for when there is no match:

```
server.all('*', async (req, res) => {
  return handle(req, res);
}
```

will handle all the other routes for you (API routes, public/static folder, etc).